# CkEditor Don't Work on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

Please Help me.
I use ckeditor_4.2_full in my mvc3 website.it works when I test it on my localhost.(in FireFox and Chrome).But when I upload my website on server, not show anything where it must be exist.why this happens?

I ref it in head of page :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and use in body this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "ckeditor", @id = "text-details" })
```

When I see page source and click on ~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js I can see behind javascript code.
thanks.

Comment: is it possible to post the url of your web page so we can see if its throwing a JavaScript exception?

Comment: http://www.hendijan.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js

Comment: I meant a page that uses the ckeditor, or are they all tucked away inside an admin panel?

Comment: yes, I use theme into admin panel.But I use it for you in index page

Comment: I guess you're working on it at the moment? I visited the main site yesterday and it was ok but http://www.hendijan.com/ is showing an error page at the moment.

Comment: please see it in this Url:http://www.hendijan.com/

Comment: Yes But now it is ok.Thak you rtpHarry

Comment: Is it working for you on the homepage? I am seeing a RTL mode ckeditor on your homepage.

Comment: yes it works on my localhost .coz it lang is farsi.

Comment: I am seeing a working copy of ckeditor on your website homepage though which you said wasn't working. Is it showing for you on your homepage?

Comment: No I can't see anything.What is  problem?

Comment: What browser are you using? Im using Firefox latest. Have you tried pressing `CTRL-F5` to force your browser to full refresh all the files?

Comment: oh god thank you so much dear. I press CTRL-F5 It solved in firefox and chrome.thank you again and again .thank for time wasted for me dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

When developing always remember to press CTRL-F5 so that all of the supporting files are reloaded.

A simple F5 just reloads the current page but doesnt flush everything out.

Side note: Some browsers can be stubborn about aggressively caching js files. In the past I have had to visit the js file by url, CTRL-F5 that and then when I've confirmed its reloaded the new version I can go back to the page that's using it.

Ive also seen the same caching issue when I've loaded in XML files through javascript (such as in Google Maps)